# String initialization in several lines

Tags: c, visual-c++

Trying to split string into several lines:

```
const char* d = "aaa\
    bbb";
```

This brings `aaa\t\tbbb` because code formatting brought two tab's before `bbb`.

If I remove tab's I have nice `aaabbb` string.

```
const char* d = "aaa\
bbb";
```

How to leave code formatting but do not put tab's in string.

Comment: `const char* d = "aaa" <any number of newlines/whitespaces> "bbb";`

Comment: [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/oszdr3476)

Comment: @yano No need in `\\` in tour demo

Comment: @EugeneSh. indeed! Fixed

Comment: FWIW, there is no single justified use-case to use the line continuation `'\'` in the C code I can think of except in macro definitions.

Answer (score 3):

Consecutive strings constants separated by whitespace are automatically concatenated by the compiler.  So you can do this:

```
const char* d = "aaa"
    "bbb";
```